# What's the UploadedImage type from the rich:fileUpload showcase from richfaces.og

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I'm testing the `rich:fileUpload` showcase from:

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload

But I can't undestand the type: `UploadedImage` , is it a class I have to create?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import it from Richfaces.

```
import org.richfaces.model.UploadedFile;
```

To get the uploaded file you can write a listener like the following one:

```
public void fileUploadListener(FileUploadEvent event)  {
       try {
            UploadedFile uploadedfile = event.getUploadedFile();
            String nomeFile = uploadedfile.getName().replace("/", "");

    // do whatever you want

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
  }
```

The UploadedImage class is a trivial class they use in their demo. Source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.richfaces.examples/richfaces-showcase/4.3.2.Final/org/richfaces/demo/fileupload/UploadedImage.java#UploadedImage). You don't need it at all, use the code above as listener and implement your own logic.

Comment: Hi! Thank you, but I didn't ask about UploadedFile, I asked about UploadedImage that is used in the bean class from the example in the link.

Comment: It's a simple class they use in their demo. Please got the source from  the link above, i just edited my post.